# XCode8 + Carthage + RATreeView (missing architecture?)

Tags: ios9, ios-simulator, xcode8, cpu-architecture, carthage

I'm a bit new to **iOS** development, and have run into an issue I can't seem to fix. I'm developing with **XCode8**, using a **Swift3 Universal Project**, which I've added various frameworks to, via **Carthage** (which up until know has worked flawlessly). The latest framework I tried to add, [RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView) (Objective-C), has given me some trouble though.

When I build I get this **Apple Mach-O Linker** warning: (ellipsis used for path brevity)

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../RATreeViewDemo/Carthage/Build/iOS/RATreeView.framework/RATreeView, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/.../RATreeViewDemo/Carthage/Build/iOS/RATreeView.framework/RATreeView (2 slices)
```

followed by this **Shell Script Invocation** error: (ellipsis used for path brevity)

```
Failed to read file or folder at /Users/.../RATreeViewDemo/Carthage/Build/iOS/RATreeView.framework
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm missing? That folder is there, and the framework file is present. I've added it to my **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**, and have a **Build Phase Script** to copy the framework appropriately... However I'm not sure how to ensure that the proper architectures are available.

As a sanity check I tried an alternate CocoaPod setup, and that seemed to work fine, but I'd really like to stick with Carthage if possible. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Just for reference, I ran "carthage update --platform iOS" to pull and build all the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because the framework you are linking against does not contain an x86_64 slice.  Presumably it just contains an armv7s and an arm64 slice (for device builds).

If this framework is from a 3rd party, you should request a version of the framework that contains intel slices as well, so you can use it when building for the simulator.

If you built this framework yourself, you will need to built it for the simulator platform in order to use it in simulator builds.

Comment: Thanks. I have contacted the author. Hopefully he can add the necessary architectures to the framework so the simulator will function.